# Find a junction by its number in Stateflow

Tags: matlab, warnings, simulink, stateflow

I'm developing an embedded system in MATLAB Simulink which contains some Stateflow charts. I successfully generate C-code out of it. Unfortunately, building the model throws up some warnings. One of them is:

```
Warning: Junction #1277 does not have an unconditional path 
to a state or a terminal junction AND it has multiple paths 
leading to it. This might lead to confusing run-time behavior 
because of the backtracking semantics of Stateflow.
```

This warning has no other link or information how to find that junction inside my model (there are plenty of junctions so it's not trivial) than its number.

Is there a way to find/highlight a junction by its number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:
Starting the build process from the "Build" button inside Simulink, rather than doing it via the MATLAB command line, creates working links in the *Diagnostic Viewer*.

Answer (score 0):

With the model open, you should be able to do the following:

```
>> sObj = sfroot;
>> myObj = sObj.find('Id',1277);
>> myObj.view
```

This will open the object in the sf viewing window.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I open the model and then type your code into the MATLAB command line, the output is:

sObj =
 
 Simulink.Root

 
myObj =
 
    handle: 0-by-1
 
Error using view (line 63)
Invalid input arguments

Comment: If `myObj` is empty then it means that there is no object with the specified Id.  The above code definitely works in R2017a and R2017b.  Not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: I used 2015b. The IDs also change from run to run, which is kind of weird